# Interfacing 3.3V Flex 6000 FPGA to a 5V CMOS DSP (Multivolt IO Question)

Tags: power-supply, fpga, dsp

I'm going to interface a 5V CMOS DSP to the 3.3V [Flex 6000](http://components.arrow.com/part/detail/42287296S7433203N7401?region=na) FPGA.

This FPGA supports 3.3V and 5V IO according to the below figure from the datasheet:

[image: Multivolt IO]

Since the FPGA I found in stock is the 3.3V version, I must connect VCCINT and VCCIO to 3.3V. The minimum Vih of the DSP is 2V. Is it safe to connect both devices together? I'm afraid this 1.3V (3.3V - 2V) isn't enough to avoid ripples or ringing effects on the signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine.

(If you have 1.3V of ripple or ringing you've got *really* big problems that need fixing before you should think about transferring data over those signals!)